# UITextview If condiion and adding `+` sign

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextview, if-statement

Hey i have a textview i need to count the string length of textview if the value is equal to 2 i need to add two `++` sign if the value is equal to 3 then i need to put one `+` and if 4 it should display invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't difficult, you really need to check the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) for NSString:

Example:

```
if ([myTextView.text length] == 2) {
    myTextView.text = [myTextView.text stringByAppendingString:@"++"];
} else if ([myTextView.text length] == 3) {
    myTextView.text = [myTextView.text stringByAppendingString:@"+"];
} if ([myTextView.text length] == 4) {
    myTextView.text = @"invalid";
}
```